# How to animate UIView.layer.shadow & UIView.center concurrently

Tags: uiview, core-animation

I'm having a bit of an issue:

I have a UIView which needs to have two animations done at the same time.

1) I need to animate the `.layer.shadowRadius`.

2) I need to animate the `.center` property (move the view from point A to point B).

I would really like to do this the "new" way using `UIView animateWithDuration:animations:`, but I can't animate the shadow in this method. I have to use CABasicAnimation as of right now.

Is there a way to combine these easily?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create two `CABasicAnimations` (for the "shadowRadius" and the "position") and configure their to and from values.

Then create a `CAAnimationGroup` and set the animations to be an array of your two animations. Now you can configure the duration, timing etc. on the animation group and it will apply to both animations.

(You add the animation group to the layer that you are animating as it contains the other two animations).

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for the tip, though :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html):

> The following properties of the UIView class are animatable:
>
> @property frame
>
> @property bounds
>
> @property center
>
> @property transform
>
> @property alpha
>
> @property backgroundColor
>
> @property contentStretch

So you can't animate the `.layer.shadowRadius` property. I guess you'll have to continue using Core Animation. Sorry.

Comment: too bad. Thanks for the answer though